# How to create a template class without errors in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm pretty new to C++ and I'm learning how to use templates. I made this simple code here with a template class to compare 2 "T" variable and return the highest value.

`TemplateClass.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class TemplateClass
{
    private:
        T a, b;

    public:

    TemplateClass() {}

    TemplateClass(T first, T second)
    {
        a = first; b = second;
    }

    T getMax();
    T getMin();
};
```

`TemplateClass.cpp`:

```
#include "TemplateClass.h"


template <class T>
inline T TemplateClass<T>::getMax()
{
    T result;
    result = a > b ? a : b;
    return result;
}

template <class T>
inline T TemplateClass<T>::getMin()
{
    T result;
    result = a < b ? a : b;
    return result;
}
```

When I'm calling the `getMax` method in my `main.cpp`, I get an error. (LNK2019 unresolved external error)

`main.cpp`:

```
int main() {
    TemplateClass<int> myobject(100, 75);
    cout << myobject.getMax();
    return 0;
}
```

When I put all my code in one cpp file (main.cpp for example), it works.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: All template code needs to be in the header file.  This is okay though, as all  template code is implicitly inline so you wont get any multiple definition errors.

Comment: So I need to just get rid of my .cpp file and put all the function definition in my header file?

Comment: Yep. copy, paste, delete, problem solved.